# Openerp-ir.values,tree_but_open ,tree_but_action explanation

Tags: xml, wizard, openerp-7

Can anyone explain me the following concept with help of an example:

1. ir.values

2.tree_but_open

3.tree_but_action

How to use them and when to use?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit old but still useful: http://openerp-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_module_dev_04.html

Answer (score 0):

"tree_but_open" gets triggered when an object is double-clicked in its model's tree view. "tree_but_action" is deprecated and currently is just an alias for "tree_but_open."

An example from addons/stock/stock_view.xml:

```
    <record id="ir_move_traceability_upstream" model="ir.values">
        <field name="key2">tree_but_action</field>
        <field name="model">stock.move</field>
        <field name="name">Downstream traceability</field>
        <field eval="'ir.actions.act_window,'+str(action3)" name="value"/>
    </record>
```

Let me know if this answers your question or if you'd like me to elaborate.

Comment: Where did you find that information? Also, can't get this to work. Clicking on a row in tree view does nothing. Odoo 8.

Comment: From reading the OpenERP source code.

Was using OpenERP 7. A lot of things changed in Odoo 8.